# Chained inheritance vs multiple inheritance for conditionally deleted special member functions

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, c++17, class-template

If the author of a class template

```
template <class T>
struct X;
```

wants to conditionally delete or default a special member function of `X<T>` depending on some property of the template parameter `T` (such as whether `T` itself supports that SMF), then prior to C++20, the only means to accomplish this is using templated base classes that are specialized to either delete or default the special member:

```
template <bool kCopyConstructible>
struct XCopyConstructorBase { };

template <>
struct XCopyConstructorBase<false> {
    XCopyConstructorBase(const XCopyConstructorBase&) = delete;
    // do not implicitly suppress any other SMFs
    XCopyConstructorBase() = default;
    XCopyConstructorBase(XCopyConstructorBase&&) = default;
    XCopyConstructorBase& operator=(const XCopyConstructorBase&) = default;
    XCopyConstructorBase& operator=(XCopyConstructorBase&&) = default;
};

template <bool kMoveConstructible>
struct XMoveConstructorBase { };

// ...
```

The implementation of `X` can then derive from each of these bases and (perhaps implicitly) default its own SMFs, which will implicitly result in them being deleted when the corresponding base class SMF is deleted:

```
template <class T>
struct X : XCopyConstructorBase<std::is_copy_constructible_v<T>>,
           XMoveConstructorBase<std::is_move_constructible_v<T>>,
           XCopyAssignmentBase<std::is_copy_assignable_v<T>>,
           XMoveAssignmentBase<std::is_move_assignable_v<T>>,
           XImpl<T> {
    // ...
};
```

(The `XImpl` base is typically needed in order to provide any nontrivial logic that the SMFs must contain while still allowing the most derived class `X<T>` to default all its SMFs.)

However, I've seen implementations that use chained inheritance instead of multiple inheritance. For example

```
template <class T> struct XImpl { /* ... */ };

template <class T, bool = std::is_copy_constructible_v<T>>
struct XCopyConstructorBase : XImpl<T> { };

template <class T>
struct XCopyConstructorBase<T, false> {
    XCopyConstructorBase(const XCopyConstructorBase&) = delete;
    // ...
};

template <class T, bool = std::is_move_constructible_v<T>>
struct XMoveConstructorBase : XCopyConstructorBase<T> { };

template <class T>
struct XMoveConstructorBase<T, false> : XCopyConstructorBase<T> {
    XMoveConstructorBase(XMoveConstructorBase&&) = delete;
    // ...
};

// ...

template <class T>
struct X : XMoveAssignmentBase<T> {
    // ...
};
```

**Are there any advantages to the chained inheritance approach over the multiple inheritance approach?**

One person suggested that perhaps, in the multiple inheritance case, some compilers might fail to make all the base classes empty. Are there any other reasons besides this?

Comment: *"some compilers might fail to make all the base classes empty."* I wonder if its actually a thing.